# R - how to repeat sequence 1 to 522

Tags: r, sequence, series

I have two files ones with 522 project id that I want to extract from the first file.

the following code works for extracting but I don't want to repeat manually 522 times the `data$projectID==datid[x, ] |`

```
data1 = data[(data$projectID==datid[1, ] |data$projectID==datid[2, ]|  ...| data$projectID==datid[522, ]), ]
```

How to repeat the instruction 522 times adding one each time.

Thanks!!

```
data = read.csv("~/Desktop/PACA SNA/PACA3.csv", header = TRUE, sep =";")

datid= read.csv("~/Desktop/PACA SNA/PACAID.csv", header = FALSE, sep =";")

data1 = data[(data$projectID==datid[1, ] | ...| data$projectID==datid[522, ]), ]
```

Comment: Have a look at `?merge`

Comment: You are not far away from presenting an https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and that would increase chances for great answers a lot. That being said, I am with @Sotos : Try if you can `merge` that.

Comment: In general, for the anti-pattern `x == a | x == b | ...`, the solution is `x %in% c(a, b, ...)`. In this case, `data1 = data[data$projectID %in% vector_of_ids]`. `vector_of_ids` needs to be `datid` if `datid` is a vector, or `datid[, "id_column"]`, if `datid` is a dataframe with the IDs in a column named `"id_column"`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a vector that contains the project ID's. Use the subset function to extract the desired data.

```
project.id <- as.vector(dataframe1$ID)
desired.data <- subset(dataframe2, dataframe2$ID %in% project.id)
```

Comment: `vector` will cause an error here. You may have meant `as.vector`, but that should be unnecessary too, `project.id <- dataframe1$ID` should do the same. (Of course, creating the extra object is optional, one could as easily use `subset(dataframe2, ID %in% dataframe1$ID)`